# Can't upload a .mdf files to Microsoft SQL Server using the GUI. Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)"

Tags: sql-server, database

I am following an old tutorial on how to use SQL Server on Pluralsight and the user is using the 2008 AdventureWorks database.

When I try to load this database in SQL Server (from https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks2008r2), I right click database, select attach and then go to the location where the `.mdf` file is.

In the Attach window, I also remove the log. However, whenever I try to attach the `.mdf` file, I can not attach it. I have tried changing the security access on the `.mdf` file, but nothing I am doing is getting the database to attach.

This is the error message I am getting:

> Attach database failed for Server 'LAPTOP-VGU43300'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
> CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are doing this in the dialogue window? What is the actual SQL you are running from that dialogue window? ([Edit] it into your question.) I assume you have verified that the file does actually exist in the location specified in the error?

Comment: Considering you are using SQL Server 2019 though, why use the 2008R2 Adventure works database, and not the [AdventureWorks2019.bak](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/adventureworks/AdventureWorks2019.bak) one?

Comment: The file location needs to have permissions that allow the SQL Server account to read and modify it